# How to make "delete" key work in Gnome 3/Nautilus and make the change stick

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome3, nautilus

In Gnome 3/Nautilus (in Fedora 17), the keyboard shortcut for moving a file to trash is `ctrl + delete`. How do I change it to just `delete`?

Answer (score 3):

Kache’s solution worked once, I think, but that seems to have changed. What worked for me was to open `~/.config/nautilus/accels`, where the second line said `; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Trash" "<Primary>Delete")`. The semicolon is a comment symbol; delete it and also remove the `<Primary>` part. Finally make sure to really restart Nautilus. (Don’t forget about a possible second instance that you may have open on another workspace like I did.)

Thanks to [Kagu](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=154684) and [dmoebius](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1263910#p1263910) for this.

Comment: This worked for me on Debian 8 Jessie

Comment: I had to do something similar on a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04.3 to restore the delete key moving files to trash... Wow, what a regression.

Answer (score 1):

1. In terminal:

   `mkdir ~/.gnome2/accels    # without this directory, the change won't stick`
2. Then: 
   `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface can-change-accels true`

   Alternatively:
   Run `dconf-editor`, navigate to org.gnome.desktop.interface and check `can-change-accels`
3. Open Nautilus, select any file, go to menu `Edit`, and highlight `Move to Trash`.
4. Hit `delete` to clear the old shortcut, and hit `delete` again to set it to `delete`.
5. Then in terminal:
   `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface can-change-accels false`

   Alternatively:
   Uncheck `can-change-accels` in `dconf-editor`

Comment: Kache's instructions work successfully on Debian Wheezy.